# Get the id of the row with the max value with two grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

We have a data structure with four columns:

```
ContractoreName, ProjectCode, InvoiceID, OrderID
```

We want to group the data by both `ContractoreName` and `ProjectCode` columns, and then get the `InvoiceID` of the row for each group with `MAX(OrderID)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT ContractorName, ProjectName, OrderId, InvoiceId
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ContractorName, ProjectName 
                                  ORDER BY OrderId DESC) AS rn
      FROM tab
) AS sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is what I would call the canonical solution.  In many cases, an old-fashioned solution has better performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.orderid = (select max(t2.orderid)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.contractorname = t.contractorname and
                         t2.projectname = t.projectname
                  );
```

This is especially true if there is an index on `(contractorname, projectname, orderid)`.

Why is this faster?  Basically, SQL Server can scan the table doing a lookup in an index.  The lookup is really fast because the index is designed for it, so the scan is just a little faster than a full table scan.

When using `row_number()`, SQL Server has to scan the table to calculate the row number (and that can use the index, so it might be fast).  But then it has to go back to the table to fetch the columns and apply the `where` clause.  So, even if it uses an index, it is doing more work.

EDIT:

I should also point out that this can be done without a subquery:

```
select distinct contractorname, projectname,
       max(orderid) over (partition by contractorname, projectname) as lastest_order,
       first_value(invoiceid) partition by (order by contractorname, projectname order by orderid desc) as lastest_invoice
from t;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't offer `first_value()` as an aggregation function, but you can use `select distinct` and get the same effect.